# How to align buttons horizontally in seperate divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to align 3 buttons horizontally in 3 seperate divs. But i just cant get it working. Im using bootstrap and the bootstrap cards:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yl6Q.png

Any idea how i can archive this with css?
Here is my html structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 card-flex mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Andrea<span><i class="fas fa-star stars first_star"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></span></h4>
        <p class="card-text read-more-wrap">Mir geht es prima, bin immer statt! Das gab es noch nie bei mir und ich habe mich heut gewogen wieder eins weniger also nun 2,5 kg nach einer Woche.<br><span id="text"> Fantastisch step by
            step aber endlich funktioniert bei mir etwas, was jahrelang nicht funktioniert hat. Bin sehr zufrieden und fühl mich super. Auf geht´s in die 2. Phase</span></p>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn" id="toggle">Read More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 card-flex mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Daniel<span><i class="fas fa-star stars first_star"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></span></h4>
        <p class="card-text read-more-wrap">Ich muss wirklich sagen das ich sehr skeptisch gegenüber dem Konzept gewesen bin. Wahrscheinlich weil ich schon so viel ausprobiert hatte. Jetzt, nach 8 Wochen habe ich 9,3 Kilo auf der Waage runter.
          <br><span id="text1"> Ich fühle mich einfach unfassbar gut, habe nicht das geringste Bedürfnis zu naschen oder zwischen den Mahlzeiten zu Essen. Das hatte ich wirklich noch NIE!</span></p>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn" id="toggle1">Read More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 card-flex mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Monika<span><i class="fas fa-star stars first_star"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></span></h4>
        <p class="card-text read-more-wrap">Kurze Info zu meiner Abnehm-Challenge:. Weitere 4 Wochen vorbei und es gibt wieder Gutes zu berichten. Die nächsten 4 Kilos sind verschwunden und das obwohl der ein oder andere "Schlampertag" dabei
          war.<br><span id="text2"> Das Konzept ist genial. Vor allen Dingen für diejenigen, wie ich, die zwar abnehmen wollen aber mit Sport nicht soviel am Hut haben.
          </span></p>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn" id="toggle2">Read More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Bootstrap grid is build with flexbox you can give the card element a `height: 100%` property. By making the card-body flex as well it is possible to align the buttons horizontally equal with `margin-top: auto`.

```css
.card {
    height: 100%;
}

.card-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card-btn {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 card-flex mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Andrea</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Mir geht es prima, bin immer statt! Das gab es noch nie bei mir und ich habe mich heut gewogen wieder eins weniger also nun 2,5 kg nach einer Woche.<br>Fantastisch step by step aber endlich funktioniert bei mir etwas, was jahrelang nicht funktioniert hat. Bin sehr zufrieden und fühl mich super. Auf geht's in die 2. Phase</p>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn">Read More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-flex mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Daniel</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Ich muss wirklich sagen das ich sehr skeptisch gegenüber dem Konzept gewesen bin. Wahrscheinlich weil ich schon so viel ausprobiert hatte. Jetzt, nach 8 Wochen habe ich 9,3 Kilo auf der Waage runter.<br>Ich fühle mich einfach unfassbar gut, habe nicht das geringste Bedürfnis zu naschen oder zwischen den Mahlzeiten zu Essen. Das hatte ich wirklich noch NIE!</p>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn">Read More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 card-flex mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Monika</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Kurze Info zu meiner Abnehm-Challenge:. Weitere 4 Wochen vorbei und es gibt wieder Gutes zu berichten. Die nächsten 4 Kilos sind verschwunden und das obwohl der ein oder andere "Schlampertag" dabei war.<br>Das Konzept ist genial. Vor allen Dingen für diejenigen, wie ich, die zwar abnehmen wollen aber mit Sport nicht soviel am Hut haben.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary card-btn">Read More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting all of that in a `<div class="container"> your code </div>` tag?

Comment: Are you correctly adding the css and js for bootstrap?

Comment: I added css and js bootstrap as explained in the bootstrap main page and everything worked normally:
[link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is in your media queries, give `.card-text` a fixed height based on the longest description you are expecting. This also retains the padding and design of the card itself.

As an example:

```
.card-text{
    height:200px;
}
```